# Saving mp3 audio from server to localstorage and updating html5 audioplayer src in JQM and phonegap

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have been trying to store an audio file from a server in local storage, and then updating my html5 audio element src to match the downloaded file.

```html
<audio id="player" controls loop >
        <source id="audio" src="#" type="audio/mp3">
        </source>
</audio>
```

And the javascript to load the file into localstorage:

```js
<script>
var filename = "test.mp3";
var audioURL = "http://myserverurl/test.mp3";

requestFileSystem(PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem) {
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.download(audioURL, fileSystem.root.toURL() + "/" + filename, function(entry) {
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.controls = 'controls';
        audioElement.src = entry.toNativeURL();
        document.audioElementById("player").appendChild(srcElement);
    });
});
</script>
```

Its not working atm, dont know where i am wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!